# Sending commands to Android's adb using redirection

Tags: android, redirect, adb, root

I have a need to send commands to `adb shell` to automate some debugging, but the catch is that I also require elevated privileges available through `su`. My first thought was to use simple file redirection:

**commands.txt**

```
ls -l > /sdcard/dirListing.txt
exit
```

`>> adb shell < commands.txt`

This approach works great, but we are limited by the privileges available to the shell only and have not elevated ourselves to root. So, I thought it would be as simple as adding an additional line that gives us these privileges.

**commands.txt**

```
su
ls -l > /sdcard/dirListing.txt
exit

>> adb shell < commands.txt
su
ls -l > /sdcard/dirListing.txt
exit
exit
```

Note : The second exit was added because after you elevate yourself using `su`, the first call to `exit` will bring you back down to your original privileges rather than terminating the session.

However, the result is far from correct. It *almost* works, I suppose. The `dirListing.txt` file is correctly generated, but, as you can see, we are left with a shell prompt with no way to interact with it. I can only assume that this is because we have redirected the input to the text file, although maybe adb is simply not handling this elevation properly and the shell is hanging.

This output is hard to follow, too.

```
su
ls -l > /sdcard/dirListing.txt
exit
exit
shell@klte:/ $ su
ls -l > /sdcard/dirListing.txt
exit
exit
ls -l > /sdcard/dirListing.txt
exit
exit
root@klte:/ # ls -l > /sdcard/dirListing.txt
root@klte:/ # exit
shell@klte:/ $
```

Any idea on how to get this to work properly?

Comment: why overcomplicate things? `adb shell 'su 0 ls -l > /sdcard/dirListing.txt'`

Comment: @AlexP, what is the `0` for in your command string? Also, what I am trying to do is many more commands than just the two as shown above.